# Start emulator with android L

Tags: android-emulator, android-5.0-lollipop

I tried creating an emulator with android L, but all I get is a black screen. When I adb into the emulator I see something like a crash loop (below). Does anyone have some step by step guide to launching an emulator with android L.

```
I/ServiceManager(   45): service 'media.audio_flinger' died
I/ServiceManager(   45): service 'media.player' died
I/ServiceManager(   45): service 'media.camera' died
I/Netd    ( 2211): Netd 1.0 starting
W/InterfaceController( 2211): Warning (dlopen failed: library "libnetcmdiface.so" not found) while opening the net interface command library
E/Netd    ( 2211): Failed to open /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/default/accept_ra_rt_table: No such file or directory
E/Netd    ( 2211): Failed to open /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth0/accept_ra_rt_table: No such file or directory
E/Netd    ( 2211): Failed to open /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/lo/accept_ra_rt_table: No such file or directory
E/Netd    ( 2211): Failed to open /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/sit0/accept_ra_rt_table: No such file or directory
I/SurfaceFlinger( 2212): SurfaceFlinger is starting
I/SurfaceFlinger( 2212): SurfaceFlinger's main thread ready to run. Initializing graphics H/W...
D/libEGL  ( 2212): Emulator without GPU support detected. Fallback to software renderer.
D/libEGL  ( 2212): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
D/gralloc_goldfish( 2212): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
E/SurfaceFlinger( 2212): hwcomposer module not found
E/SurfaceFlinger( 2212): ERROR: failed to open framebuffer (No such file or directory), aborting
F/libc    ( 2212): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 2212 (surfaceflinger)
I/DEBUG   (   52): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   (   52): Build fingerprint: 'generic/google_sdk/generic:L/LPV81B/1242878:eng/test-keys'
I/DEBUG   (   52): Revision: '0'
I/DEBUG   (   52): pid: 2212, tid: 2212, name: surfaceflinger  >>> /system/bin/surfaceflinger <<<
I/DEBUG   (   52): signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
I/DEBUG   (   52):     r0 00000000  r1 000008a4  r2 00000006  r3 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   52):     r4 00000006  r5 00000002  r6 000008a4  r7 0000010c
I/DEBUG   (   52):     r8 b8529698  r9 bef2c9f8  sl fffffffe  fp bef2cb5c
I/DEBUG   (   52):     ip b6fc3e9c  sp bef2c990  lr b6f82a15  pc b6fa529c  cpsr 00000010
I/DEBUG   (   52):     d0  0000000000000000  d1  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   52):     d2  0000000000000000  d3  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   52):     d4  0000000000000000  d5  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   52):     d6  0000000000000000  d7  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   52):     d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   52):     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   52):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   52):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   52):     scr 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   52): 
I/DEBUG   (   52): backtrace:
I/DEBUG   (   52):     #00 pc 0003829c  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
I/DEBUG   (   52):     #01 pc 00015a11  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+64)
I/DEBUG   (   52):     #02 pc 000164f1  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
I/DEBUG   (   52):     #03 pc 00013399  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+36)
I/DEBUG   (   52):     #04 pc 0001259c  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
I/DEBUG   (   52):     #05 pc 0001cf67  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so
I/DEBUG   (   52):     #06 pc 00018337  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so (android::SurfaceFlinger::init()+78)
I/DEBUG   (   52):     #07 pc 000007e1  /system/bin/surfaceflinger
I/DEBUG   (   52):     #08 pc 0000f623  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+50)
I/DEBUG   (   52):     #09 pc 000008d8  /system/bin/surfaceflinger
I/DEBUG   (   52): 
I/DEBUG   (   52): stack:
I/DEBUG   (   52):          bef2c950  b6839004  /system/lib/hw/gralloc.default.so
I/DEBUG   (   52):          bef2c954  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   52):          bef2c958  b85297a8  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   52):          bef2c95c  b6839004  /system/lib/hw/gralloc.default.so
I/DEBUG   (   52):          bef2c960  fffffffe  
I/DEBUG   (   52):          bef2c964  b68390c4  /system/lib/hw/gralloc.default.so
I/DEBUG   (   52):          bef2c968  b8529684  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   52):          bef2c96c  b6837483  /system/lib/hw/gralloc.default.so (fb_device_open(hw_module_t const*, char const*, hw_device_t**)+98)
I/DEBUG   (   52):          bef2c970  b6e50f4b  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so
I/DEBUG   (   52):          bef2c974  b68391c4  /system/lib/hw/gralloc.default.so
I/DEBUG   (   52):          bef2c978  00000006  
I/DEBUG   (   52):          bef2c97c  00000002  
I/DEBUG   (   52):          bef2c980  000008a4  
I/DEBUG   (   52):          bef2c984  b6fc3e9c  
I/DEBUG   (   52):          bef2c988  b8529698  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   52):          bef2c98c  b6f82a09  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+56)
I/DEBUG   (   52):     #00  bef2c990  00000006  
I/DEBUG   (   52):          ........  ........
I/DEBUG   (   52):     #01  bef2c990  00000006  
I/DEBUG   (   52):          bef2c994  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   52):          bef2c998  bef2c9b0  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (   52):          bef2c99c  b6f834f5  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+14)
I/DEBUG   (   52):     #02  bef2c9a0  bef2c9ac  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (   52):          bef2c9a4  b6f8039d  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+40)
I/DEBUG   (   52): 
I/DEBUG   (   52): memory near r8:
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b8529678 00207265 0000012b b8527508 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b8529688 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b8529698 b6e57ae0 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b85296a8 00000018 00000000 00000001 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b85296b8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b85296c8 b85266f0 b85266f0 00000000 b85266f0  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b85296d8 00000000 b6e57ae0 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b85296e8 00000000 00000018 00000000 00000001  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b85296f8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b8529708 00000000 b85266f0 b85266f0 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b8529718 b85266f0 00000000 b6e57ae0 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b8529728 00000000 00000000 00000018 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b8529738 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b8529748 00000000 00000000 b85266f0 b85266f0  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b8529758 00000000 b85266f0 00000000 00000001  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b8529768 b8529568 b852751c 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   52): 
I/DEBUG   (   52): memory near r9:
I/DEBUG   (   52):     bef2c9d8 b6e20030 00000000 00000000 b6e1de54  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     bef2c9e8 00000001 00000001 bef2ca14 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     bef2c9f8 b6e10030 00000000 b6e0470b b6fd55ef  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     bef2ca08 b6e5a4e4 b6fd5689 b6e1de54 b6fea0e0  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     bef2ca18 b6e2b2f4 b6e1de54 bef2ca44 bef2ca44  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     bef2ca28 0000012b 00000838 b8529680 00000003  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     bef2ca38 b6fed77d b6f7e1a3 b6fc0020 00000120  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     bef2ca48 bef2cac8 b6e4f944 bef2cb04 1c5019d5  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     bef2ca58 b8527508 bef2cac8 b6e4f944 b8529680  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     bef2ca68 b6fed77d 00000000 00000000 b6e4533b  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     bef2ca78 b6fed77d b6f7e1a3 b6fc0020 00000010  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     bef2ca88 b6f1c0a4 b6f14bf1 00000001 000008a4  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     bef2ca98 00000001 000008a4 00000001 b6f14f73  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     bef2caa8 b6f0e950 b8527520 b85294d4 b6f075e1  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     bef2cab8 b85276a4 b6e40ceb b8527228 bef2cadc  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     bef2cac8 b8527508 31323201 bef20032 bef2cb0c  
I/DEBUG   (   52): 
I/DEBUG   (   52): memory near fp:
I/DEBUG   (   52):     bef2cb3c 00000000 00000000 b6fed8dc b6feee6c  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     bef2cb4c b6feee74 b6feee7c bef2cb60 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     bef2cb5c b6fd7cd1 00000001 bef2cc49 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     bef2cb6c bef2cc64 bef2cca1 bef2ccb4 bef2ccc9  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     bef2cb7c bef2cce4 bef2ccf7 bef2cd10 bef2cd2a  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     bef2cb8c bef2cd43 bef2cf87 bef2cfa1 bef2cfc2  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     bef2cb9c 00000000 00000010 0000b0d7 00000006  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     bef2cbac 00001000 00000011 00000064 00000003  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     bef2cbbc b6fed034 00000004 00000020 00000005  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     bef2cbcc 00000008 00000007 b6fd4000 00000008  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     bef2cbdc 00000000 00000009 b6fed878 0000000b  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     bef2cbec 000003e8 0000000c 000003e8 0000000d  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     bef2cbfc 000003eb 0000000e 000003eb 00000017  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     bef2cc0c 00000000 00000019 bef2cc35 0000001f  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     bef2cc1c bef2cfe1 0000000f bef2cc45 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     bef2cc2c 00000000 00000000 5019d500 103d5e1c  
I/DEBUG   (   52): 
I/DEBUG   (   52): memory near ip:
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b6fc3e7c 00010000 00200000 00000003 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b6fc3e8c b852a000 bef2cba0 bef2cc49 bef2cb6c  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b6fc3e9c 1c5019d5 00000000 b6fea980 00000007  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b6fc3eac 00000008 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b6fc3ebc 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b6fc3ecc 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b6fc3edc 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b6fc3eec 00000009 00000000 b8523008 b8523008  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b6fc3efc 00000000 00000000 b85291f8 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b6fc3f0c 00000001 00003fff 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b6fc3f1c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b6fc3f2c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b6fc3f3c 00000000 b6f8152d b6f81531 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b6fc3f4c b6f838fd b6f83a29 00000000 b6f39409  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b6fc3f5c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b6fc3f6c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   52): 
I/DEBUG   (   52): memory near sp:
I/DEBUG   (   52):     bef2c970 b6e50f4b b68391c4 00000006 00000002  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     bef2c980 000008a4 b6fc3e9c b8529698 b6f82a09  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     bef2c990 00000006 00000000 bef2c9b0 b6f834f5  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     bef2c9a0 bef2c9ac b6f8039d b6fc3e9c ffffffdf  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     bef2c9b0 b6e50ece 1c5019d5 bef2cb5c b8529680  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     bef2c9c0 b8529680 00000000 00000000 b6f7f5a0  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     bef2c9d0 1c5019d5 b6e49f6b b6e20030 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     bef2c9e0 00000000 b6e1de54 00000001 00000001  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     bef2c9f0 bef2ca14 00000000 b6e10030 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     bef2ca00 b6e0470b b6fd55ef b6e5a4e4 b6fd5689  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     bef2ca10 b6e1de54 b6fea0e0 b6e2b2f4 b6e1de54  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     bef2ca20 bef2ca44 bef2ca44 0000012b 00000838  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     bef2ca30 b8529680 00000003 b6fed77d b6f7e1a3  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     bef2ca40 b6fc0020 00000120 bef2cac8 b6e4f944  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     bef2ca50 bef2cb04 1c5019d5 b8527508 bef2cac8  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     bef2ca60 b6e4f944 b8529680 b6fed77d 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   52): 
I/DEBUG   (   52): code around pc:
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b6fa527c e1a0700c e3700a01 912fff1e e2600000  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b6fa528c ea002f6b e1a0c007 e3a07f43 ef000000  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b6fa529c e1a0700c e3700a01 912fff1e e2600000  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b6fa52ac ea002f63 e1a0c007 e59f7014 ef000000  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b6fa52bc e1a0700c e3700a01 912fff1e e2600000  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b6fa52cc ea002f5b 0000013a e1a0c007 e59f7014  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b6fa52dc ef000000 e1a0700c e3700a01 912fff1e  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b6fa52ec e2600000 ea002f52 00000177 e1a0c007  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b6fa52fc e59f7014 ef000000 e1a0700c e3700a01  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b6fa530c 912fff1e e2600000 ea002f49 00000163  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b6fa531c e1a0c00d e92d00f0 e89c0070 e59f7014  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b6fa532c ef000000 e8bd00f0 e3700a01 912fff1e  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b6fa533c e2600000 ea002f3e 00000122 e1a0c00d  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b6fa534c e92d00f0 e89c0070 e3a070e2 ef000000  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b6fa535c e8bd00f0 e3700a01 912fff1e e2600000  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b6fa536c ea002f33 e1a0c007 e3a070b1 ef000000  
I/DEBUG   (   52): 
I/DEBUG   (   52): code around lr:
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b6f829f4 44782403 fa10f000 689ee011 4478480d  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b6f82a04 fa0af000 ec88f023 46224631 ec3ef022  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b6f82a14 d1033001 ff7ef7fd e0006804 f7fd2400  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b6f82a24 6005ff79 bd704620 00041526 0004151a  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b6f82a34 0004150e 00041502 41f3e92d bf0c2900  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b6f82a44 0880f04f 0800f04f 46144606 f7fd461f  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b6f82a54 4631ff61 46424623 20f06805 f7fd9700  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b6f82a64 1c43e8b8 d1064606 ff54f7fd 42466800  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b6f82a74 ff50f7fd 46306005 e8bdb002 e92d81f0  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b6f82a84 46044ff7 46886805 f4154691 f4054740  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b6f82a94 f0005600 f7ff8087 6883fdeb 4f15ebb3  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b6f82aa4 f5b7d11c d0794f00 76fcf641 0706ea05  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b6f82ab4 71fcf641 d073428f 0e04f105 8f00e854  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b6f82ac4 0000f04f 0f05ea98 e844bf08 2800e000  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b6f82ad4 45a8d1f4 8092f000 e7ed6825 0b07ea46  
I/DEBUG   (   52):     b6f82ae4 455d0418 f045d111 ea410101 e8540700  
I/mediaserver( 2213): ServiceManager: 0xb74526b0
I/AudioFlinger( 2213): Using default 3000 mSec as standby time.
I/CameraService( 2213): CameraService started (pid=2213)
I/ServiceManager(   45): service 'media.audio_flinger' died
I/ServiceManager(   45): service 'media.player' died
```

Answer (score 5):

Try checking 'Use Host GPU' in 'Emulator Options' section of your AVD device  (open AVD, select your device, click edit).

Comment: Don't know if this answer helped the original poster, but it was correct for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
E/Netd    ( 2211): Failed to open /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/default/accept_ra_rt_table: No such file or directory
E/Netd    ( 2211): Failed to open /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth0/accept_ra_rt_table: No such file or directory
E/Netd    ( 2211): Failed to open /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/lo/accept_ra_rt_table: No such file or directory
E/Netd    ( 2211): Failed to open /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/sit0/accept_ra_rt_table: No such file or directory
```

I think this information should be the focus, you can track it.

Comment: No its not, `ERROR: failed to open framebuffer ` is what leads to the crash, the inability to open network devices has nothing todo with it. In addition to that this is not an answer, and should be a comment(if you cant comment yet refrain from posting "comment answers").